# Textbox unique value in Laravel,vuejs,Axios, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to be displayed the toastr popup message when the user try to insert the duplicate value for BageCode in form the if anyone can help me it will be so kind of him.
I the rest form column validation is working the toaster is working but I don't know how to compare the data from database and data in form 
like this

> if (this.form.BadgeCode == data.BadgeCode) {
>                     toast.fire({
>                       type: "warning",
>                       title: "The badge code has already been taken."
>                     });
>                   }

**Code in EmployeeController is:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $date=\Carbon\Carbon::today();
        //  $this->authorize('isAdmin');
        $employee=Employee::where('expiredate','>',$date)->paginate(5);
    // return Employee::all();
    return response()->json($employee);
   }


public function store(Request $request)
        {

        //    $this->authorize('isAdmin');
            $this->validate($request,[           
                // 'BadgeCode'=>'required|string',  
               'BadgeCode'=>'required|unique:employees,BadgeCode',
                'BadgeType'=>'required', 
     ])             'company_id'=>'required',
    }
```

**Code in api route is:**

```
Route::apiResources(['employee'=>'API\EmployeeController']);
```

**Code in Employee.vue is:**

```
   <div
      style="width:45%;margin-left: 35%;"
      class="modal fade"
      id="addNew"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="addNewLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="!editMode" id="addNewLabel">Add New employee</h5>
            <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="editMode" id="addNewLabel">Update employee's Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form
            @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateemployee() : createemployee()"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
          >
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  name="company_id"
                  id="company_id"
                  :class="{'is-invalid':form.errors.has('company_id')}"
                  class="form-control"
                  v-model="form.company_id"
                >
                  <option value selected>Select Company</option>
                  <option
                    v-for="Company in Companies"
                    :key="Company.id"
                    :value="Company.id"
                  >{{Company.Company}}</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="company_id"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.BadgeCode"
                  placeholder="Enter BadgeCode"
                  type="text"
                  name="BadgeCode"
                  class="form-control"
                />
                <!-- :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('BadgeCode') }" -->
                <!-- <has-error :form="form" field="BadgeCode"></has-error> -->
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  name="BadgeType"
                  v-model="form.BadgeType"
                  id="BadgeType"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{'is-invalid':form.errors.has('BadgeType')}"
                >
                  <option value selected>Select BadgeType</option>
                  <option value="Resident">Resident</option>
                  <option value="Non-Resident-Expat">Non-Resident Expat</option>
                  <option value="Non-Resident-LN">Non-Resident LN</option>
                  <option value="Baron-employee">Baron-employee</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="BadgeType"></has-error>
              </div>

            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Code in script is:**

```
<script>

export default {
  // el: "#wrapper2",


  data() {
    return {          
      seen: false,
      seen2: true,
      color: "blue",
      size: "20px",
      editMode: false,
      Companies: {},
      employees: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        BadgeCode: "",
        BadgeType: "",
        company_id: "",

      })
    };
  },
  methods: {


    getvalidateion() {
      axios.get("api/employee").then(response => {
        let data = response.data.data;


        if (data) {
          data.forEach(element => {
            if (this.form.BadgeCode == data.BadgeCode) {
              toast.fire({
                type: "warning",
                title: "The badge code has already been taken."
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log("NO DATA");
        }
      });
    },
    createemployee() {
      this.getvalidateion();
      if (this.form.company_id == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please Select the Company."
        });
      } else if (this.form.BadgeCode == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "BadgeCode is required."
        });
      } else if (this.form.BadgeType == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please Select the BadgeType."
        });
      } else if (this.form.nationality_id == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please Select the Nationality."
        });
      } else if (this.form.expiredate == "" || this.form.issuedate == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please fill the issuedate or expiredate fileds ."
        });
      } else if (this.form.photo.length == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please select photo."
        });
      } else if (
        this.form.afghanidatephoto != undefined &&
        this.form.afghanidatephoto.length == ""
      ) {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          title: "Please select AfghaniDate."
        });
      } else {
        this.form
          .post("api/employee")
          .then(() => {
            //    the below function will be use to reload the page

            //   this.$emit("refreshPage");
            $("#addNew").modal("hide");
            toast.fire({
              type: "success",
              title: "employee Created successfully"
            });

            this.form.reset();
            $("#afghanidatephoto").val("");
            $("#photo").val("");
            Fire.$emit("refreshPage");

          })
          .catch(e => {

            console.log(e);
          });
      }
    },



  created() {
    Fire.$on("searching", () => {
      let query = this.$parent.search;
      axios
        .get("api/findemployee?q=" + query)
        .then(data => {
          this.employees = data.data;
        })

        .catch(() => {});
    });
    this.loademployees();
    this.getvalidateion();
    // load the page after 3 secound
    Fire.$on("refreshPage", () => {
      this.loademployees();
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

**Code in Modal  is:**

```
 $table->string('BadgeCode')->unique();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution** instate of data.BadgeCode I should have put element.BadgeCode anyway thanks guys

```
getvalidateion() {
      axios.get(this.url).then(response => {
        let data = response.data;
        //this.Companies != undefined && this.Companies.length == 0
        if (data) {
          data.forEach(element => {
            this.employees2.push(element.BadgeCode);
            if (this.form.BadgeCode == element.BadgeCode) {
              toast.fire({
                type: "warning",
                title: "BadgeCode is already has been taken."
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log("NO DATA");
        }
      });
    }
```